# How can I validate multiple input fields to match certain condition?

Tags: reactjs, validation

I've got 4 input fields which I need to validate according to each other's input.

So if maximum amount is above 50000 it has to give an error: Maximum amount shouldn't be above 50000

As soon as any input field has changed and maximum amount is below 50000 then error should disappear.

But it is not false for all input and it keep returning truthy in this scenario:

```
Input1 60000 //ERROR
Input2 10 //ERROR
Input3 10 //ERROR
Input4 10 //ERROR


Input1 40000 //VALID
Input2 10 //ERROR
Input3 10 //ERROR
Input4 10 //ERROR
```

So I need Input2,3,4 to show VALID as soon as Input1 has been changed and Input1 + Input2 + Input3 + Input4 are below 50000

Here is my function:

```
 let sum = input1 + input2 + input3 + input4
        const validator= () => {
            if( sum > 50000){
                return "Shouln't be above 50000"
            }
        };
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you have 4 inputs, you will have to create 4 refs for your inputs and one state to store the error flag. After this you have to use the onChange event of each input and call this validate function. one sample code should look like this.

```
import React from 'react'
export const Sample = (props) => {
    const [isError, setIsError] = useState(false);
    const input1 = useRef();
    const input2 = useRef();
    const input3 = useRef();
    const input4 = useRef();

    const validateInputs = () => {
        let sum = input1 + input2 + input3 + input4;
        if (sum > 5000) {
            setIsError(true)
        }
        else {
            setIsError(false)
        }


    }

    return (
        <>

            <input type='text' value={input1} onChange={() => { input1(e.target.value); validateInputs(); }} />
            {isError ? <div>this input has got error</div> : null}

            <input type='text' value={input2} onChange={() => { input2(e.target.value); validateInputs(); }} />
            {isError ? <div>this input has got error</div> : null}

            <input type='text' value={input3} onChange={() => { input3(e.target.value); validateInputs(); }} />
            {isError ? <div>this input has got error</div> : null}

            <input type='text' value={input4} onChange={() => { input4(e.target.value); validateInputs(); }} />
            {isError ? <div>this input has got error</div> : null}
        </>
    )
}
```

basically you have to use the refs and state value toggle. if you are using class component use createRef (there is lots of documentation available on internet)